# C LibPCRE match digit before static delimiter issue

Tags: c, regex, pcre

In have the following match pattern in a C code:

```
static const char my_pattern[] = "([0-9]{20})[\\^]";
```

and the following string:

> 12345678901234567890^otherstrings^and^digits12345678901234567890

I want to match only:

```
12345678901234567890
```

why my result is:

> 12345678901234567890^

?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Full code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>

static const char my_pattern[] = "([0-9]{20})[\\^]";
static pcre* my_pcre = NULL;
static pcre_extra* my_pcre_extra = NULL;

void my_match(const char* src)
{
    printf("src: %s\n", src);
    int ovector[30]={0};
    int retex = pcre_exec(my_pcre, NULL, src, strlen(src), 0, 0, ovector, 30);
    if (retex == PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH){
        printf("None match.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Matches %d\n", retex);
        const char *sp = NULL;
        pcre_get_substring((const char *)src, ovector, retex, 0, &sp);
        printf("%s\n", sp);
        pcre_free_substring(sp);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    const char* err;
    int erroffset;
    my_pcre = pcre_compile(my_pattern, PCRE_CASELESS, &err, &erroffset, NULL);
    my_pcre_extra = pcre_study(my_pcre, 0, &err);
    my_match("12345678901234567890^otherstrings^and^digits12345678901234567890");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any code please? also your pattern should have only digit `([0-9]{20}) `not `^` because you want to match this.

Comment: In that string I want to match the `20 digits` before `^` but not `^`, my regex matches the `^` too.

Comment: what about `^[0-9]{20,}`?

Comment: And where is the `^` delimiter?

Comment: You want to consume the `^`, but capture the group before it, correct?

Comment: hi @WhozCraig! :) Correct. So I match only the `20 digits` before `^` and not the other digits. What is strange, on `regex101.com` my regex shows as correct.

Comment: Then use the first capture group, not the full capture. I.e `i=1`. I think you know what I'm talking about, but i'll post it anyway.

Comment: @xtmtrx ok. hope that helps. I'm gonna keep my eye on your Mac question, btw. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig, yeah, trying to "port" the code we worked (Linux proc / pcre) to MacOS X :) BTW, Mac's Xcode is just awesome with all the help you can get from its advices when compiling :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE captures are in the output vector in pairs. Your full match is in the first pair, the sub-group capture is in the second. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>

static const char subject[] =
    "12345678901234567890^otherstrings^and^digits12345678901234567890";

#define OVSIZE  9

int main()
{
    static const char my_pattern[] = "([0-9]{20})[\\^]";
    const char *errtext = NULL;
    int errofs = 0;
    pcre* re = pcre_compile(my_pattern, 0, &errtext, &errofs, NULL);
    if (re != NULL)
    {
        int ov[OVSIZE];
        int rc = pcre_exec(re, NULL, subject, sizeof(subject), 0, 0, ov, OVSIZE);
        if (rc >= 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<rc; ++i)
                printf("group %d: %.*s\n", i, ov[2*i+1]-ov[2*i], subject+ov[2*i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
group 0: 12345678901234567890^
group 1: 12345678901234567890
```

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig! Fast as always ;)

Comment: @xtmtrx just hope it helps. I'm pretty sure you can do it anyway with just a single expression (ignore-if kinda of condition) but I'm too tired to refresh my re-brain. sry. =P

Comment: Thanks man! Can do it from now on. Anyway I know there is a PCRE pattern to match only `[0-9]{20}` before `^`

Comment: @xtmtrx Excellent. Btw you may find `"([0-9]{20})(?:\\^||$)"` useful if your string can *end* with a 20-digit run, but no delimiter. Have a great day!

Comment: Found it: `([0-9]{20})(?=\\^)` have a great day too @WhozCraig, happy always to see you around :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the REGEX pattern I was looking for:

```
([0-9]{20})(?=\\^)
```

or, more elegant:

```
([\\d]{20})(?=\\^)
```

Comment: Or `"([\\d]{20})(?=\\^||$)"` if your last string on the line doesn't end with a delimiter (thanks for the hint about look-ahead-with-ignore, gawd my re's are rusty).